R: Annotating regression equation on plot using ggplotly
I am working on a shiny app that plots a few regressions and I was asked to make those plots interactive so folks can hover over the various points, so I figured I would just use ggplotly to do this. The only problem is that the regression equation doesn't seem to play well with plotly.
Here is an example bit of code. Any ideas on how to display this correctly?
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(ggpubr)


df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
df$yy <- 2 + 3 * df$x + 0.1 * df$x^2 + rnorm(100, sd = 40)


p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  stat_regline_equation(aes(label =  paste(..eq.label..,..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")))

ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = TRUE)

This is what I get when I run that code:
Desired output, but made interactive via plotly
Update:  This code fixed my issue, thanks!!
library(plotly)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggplot2)



df <- data.frame(x = c(1:100))
df$y <- 2 + 3 * df$x + rnorm(100, sd = 40)
df$yy <- 2 + 3 * df$x + 0.1 * df$x^2 + rnorm(100, sd = 40)

my.formula <- y ~ x

p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = my.formula)+
stat_poly_eq(geom = "text", # override default "text_npc"
             output.type = "text",  # override default "expression"
             formula = my.formula,
             aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = ",  ")), # use for sep plain text
             label.x = 20) + # override default "left"
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p, dynamicTicks = TRUE)


As explained here, you could use a output.type with "text" to format them properly in ggplotly.

Thanks Quinten!!  That did the trick.  Not sure why that didn't pop up in my google searches earlier.  Have a great day!!

Rather than posting your answer as an edit, add it as an answer. Self-answering is encouraged on SO. You can accept your own answer too. Although accepting your own answer will not gain you rep points, it will let others know that the question has been solved.
